# Mongoexport error parsing query

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Im trying to do a mongoexport to CSV but only selecting certain records with a query. Here's my command (windows 7 cmd):

```
mongoexport --host foo.com --port 27017 --username bar -p --db foo --csv --fields col1,col2,col3 --collection bar --out dump_q.csv --query '{"recent":"yes"}'
```

However after entering the password, I get an error:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0
```

The command works fine without the query argument but I cant figure out whats wrong with the query:

```
--query '{"recent":"yes"}'
```

Any help much appreciated

---

### Summary of answer:

1. Make sure you use double quotes on enclose the query and single quotes to enclose strings e.g.

   --query "{'recent':'yes'}"
2. Also make sure you don't have a space in your query otherwise the command prompt will parse it as another argument. So **don't have**:

   --query "{'recent': 'yes'}"
   (notice the space in-between)
3. Queries which include nested fields don't work such as:

   --query "{'folder.recent':'yes'}"

Comment: What if I need to add spaces e.g. in creating date: `new Date()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use double quotes to contain the query string (and either single quotes or two quotes to escape inside of the string)

```
--query "{'recent':'yes'}"
```

Complete:

```
mongoexport --host foo.com --port 27017 --username bar -p
        --db foo --csv --fields col1,col2,col3 
        --collection bar --out dump_q.csv --query "{'recent':'yes'}"
```

Comment: The line you provided works as I've described (I tried it). I'd imagine you're trying on a more complex command-line?

Comment: ( the first time I tried it I had a space in it e.g. "{'recent': 'yes'}" )

Answer (score 0):

From [mongoexport documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query):

> --query , -q
>
> ```
> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents returned in the export.
> ```

Your query string seems to be correctly formated. You can even ommit the double quotes around *recent*.

Single or double quotes don't seem to matter, as long as you are persistent in using different types on the outside and the inside.

Are you sure this is a valid query though? What is the output if you run the following in the database? What about a *find()*?

```
db.bar.count({"recent":"yes"})
```