# MongoDB mongoexport query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of the following form in MongoDB.
As you can see some documends have two members "id" and "xid" and some have only 1 "id" (aside from the Object _id)

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
    },

    {
        "id" : 2,
    },

    {
       "id" : 3
       "xid": 300
    }
]
```

I want to create a mongoexport statement that exports to a csv only documents with id's AND xid's with the value of xid > 0

I currently have the following command:

```
mongoexport -h host -u user -p pass --db database --collection collections --csv --fields id,xid --query '{"xid":{"$ne":0}}' --out rec.csv
```

However this also exports documents that have an id without an xid. So i get something like

```
xid, id
12, 3
,4
14, 5
,3
,2
12, 5
```

etc.

Is there a way to export documents that only have both id and xid?

Comment: --query "{'xid':{'$ne':0}}" double quotes outside and single quotes inside

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456714/mongoexport-error-parsing-query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following as your query:

```
{ $and: [
    {xid: {$exists:true}},
    {xid:{$gt:0}}
    ]  
}
```

[$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) "performs a logical AND operation on an array of two or more expressions (e.g. , , etc.) and selects the documents that satisfy all the expressions in the array."

[$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) checks if the specific field is present in the document.

Also, as it is being pointed out by Vijay, in your description you mention you want xid > 0. You shouldn't be using $ne (not equal), but $gt (greater than).

Answer (score 20):

you can use below commands

```
mongoexport -d database_name -c collection_name --csv --query { id:{$exist:true},xid:{$gt:0}}
```

Answer (score 5):

mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --query "{'Name':'Vijil'}" --out file_name.json

Comment: add some explanation

Answer (score 5):

Remember as of `3.0.6` `--csv` tag is not supported, now in order to use that use `--type=csv`

Below is the query which takes MongoExport on the database `db_name` and collection `collection_name`, Remember to specify field names also(which fields you want to add in your csv file).

```
sudo mongoexport -d db_name -c collection_name --type=csv --query='{field1:{$gt:2}}' -f "field1,field2" --sort='{field1:-1}' -u 'username' -p 'passwd' --authenticationDatabase=admin --out dir/file.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change your query to

```
--query {id: {$exists : true}, xid: {$gt : 0}}
```

This above query will return only those documents that have id field and have value of xid > 0. So if there is any document that have only id field not xid, those documents will not be returned.

Answer (score 1):

From the document given above, it seems it is an array of documents, but you are accessing the document without . notation. Seems you are accessing the document wrongly.

Should be something like  `'{"key.xid":{"$ne":0}}'`